# Strange behavior of a static class

Tags: c#, static, race-condition

I have a system that can be lock by multiple reasons.
Here is the static class, in charge of keeping the lock states:

```
internal static class Locker
{
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    internal static bool LockedByReason1 { get; set; }
    internal static bool LockedByReason2 { get; set; }
    internal static bool LockedByReason3 { get; set; }

    internal static bool Locked
    {
        get
        {
            log.DebugFormat("LockedByReason1: {0}, LockedByReason2: {1}, LockedByReason3: {2}", LockedByReason1, LockedByReason2, LockedByReason3);
            return LockedByReason1 || LockedByReason2 || LockedByReason3;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in the business logic:

```
Locker.LockedByReason1 = false;
if (Locker.Locked)
    log.Info("Unlocking system...");
else
    log.Info("Not unlocking system");
```

My log file show this text:

```
2014-06-06 10:54:31,765 DEBUG Client.Utils.Locker - LockedByReason1: False, LockedByReason2: False, LockedByReason3: False
2014-06-06 10:54:31,765 INFO Client.BusinessLogicManager - Not unlocking system
```

As you can see, the setting of the `LockedByReason1` property and querying the `Locked` state were called at the same time.
Do I have here a race condition problem?
Is it because the `Locker` class is static?

Comment: I think it all works properly: you are setting `LockedByReason1` to `False`, the printout says it's `False`, all three items are `False`, so the "OR" of them is also `False`, and so the `if` takes the branch on `False`. What did you expect to happen differently?

Comment: I wouldn't read too much into the timestamps. It is likely that the system clock did not update between calls to the logging system. Typically it updates every 15ms. Time between those two items being logged is on the order of 10s of nanoseconds.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I thought this was a lock or threads problem, but apparently sometimes you have to raise your head from the keyboard, take a deep breath and realize that it was only a missing exclamation mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you have a race condition here; no, it's not because the class is `static`.

The problem is that between the `LockedByReason1 = false` and the reading of `Locker.Locked` (which is itself far, *far* from an atomic operation) other threads may execute code that makes your lock condition true.

In general this design does not offer any protection from race conditions at all because it uses neither atomic operations nor synchronization primitives (e.g. the `lock` statement).

Comment: Are you sure he's not simply missing an exclamation point before `Locker.Locked` in his `if` condition?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: He is, but there is a glaring race condition, and that's what the question asks...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't any race condition here, because there is no race. This is just sequential single thread operations. You've all LockedByReason values set to false (bool fields are false plus default and you also set LockedByReason1 to false). In conditional statement you check the Locked value and this gave the first log record. Results is false and this results in the second, "Not unlocking system" log record. The same time records in log are because output is much faster than DateTime precision.

But you code isn't thread safe. So a little bit optimized version, without using of expensive "lock" instruction might look as:

```
internal static class Locker
{
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    // We join or lockers into one field, because boolean cann't be handled by Interlocked routines.
    private static volatile int _Lockers = 0;

    // Thread-safe update routine
    internal static void AtomicUpdate(int mask, bool value)
    {
        SpinWait sw = new SpinWait();
        do
        {
            int old = _Lockers;
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _Lockers, value ? old | mask : old &~mask, old) == old)
            {
                return;
            }

            sw.SpinOnce();
        } while (true);
    }

    // Reason 1 will be the first bit of _Lockers field, Reason 2 - the second and so on.
    internal static bool LockedByReason1
    {
        get
        {
            return (_Lockers & 1) > 0;
        }
        set
        {
            Locker.AtomicUpdate(1, value);
        }
    }

    internal static bool LockedByReason2
    {
        get
        {
            return (_Lockers & 2) > 0;
        }
        set
        {
            Locker.AtomicUpdate(2, value);
        }
    }

    internal static bool LockedByReason3
    {
        get
        {
            return (_Lockers & 4) > 0;
        }
        set
        {
            Locker.AtomicUpdate(4, value);
        }
    }

    internal static bool Locked
    {
        get
        {
            log.DebugFormat("LockedByReason1: {0}, LockedByReason2: {1}, LockedByReason3: {2}", LockedByReason1, LockedByReason2, LockedByReason3);
            return _Lockers > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this technically threadsafe. Even though the `Interlocked.Exchange` call itself is threadsafe, I don't think the gathering of its values, specifically the expressions like `_Lockers | 2` are threadsafe. It's plausible that when `_Lockers_` is `0`, and `LockByReason1` and `LockByReason2` setters are called simultaneously, that they both read the `_Lockers` field at the same time and evaluate their expressions as: `0 | 1` and `0 | 2` and whichever `Exchange` call happens last will win throwing out the old value.

Comment: You're definitely right. There were some another errors in code. Have updated.

Comment: Holy smokes. In my experience, when it comes to _correct_ multithreaded code, it's almost always better to use a standard `lock` around a private locking object. Only start optimizing the threading aspects once you have a truly measurable impact caused by a standard `lock`. Glancing at the code you have now, I wouldn't be able to say that there are no threading issues with it anymore, let alone inspecting it months later.

Comment: May be. Just know, that MS uses the same solution in the same use case, for example - state management in System.Threading.Task class. And I'm also agreed with Jeffrey Richter (CLR via C#): "Personally, I love the Interlocked methods, because they are relatively fast and you can do so much with them". That's why I've decided that this is a good approach. I think that if smth is too complex for you, there is a good place for improvement))

Comment: I think anyone should be open to learn new things, but I don't think a SO answer for someone who is just starting to get a handle on threadsafety then throwing spinwaits and bitwise operations are the way to go. In this case, to help toy4fun be _productive_ and _correct_ in his day-to-day development of C# I'd say a much more effective example _to answer this question_ would be one that uses a standard `lock` and ditch the single backing field altogether (or at worst use a flags enum). I like `Interlocked` too, but I always favour readability and maintainability over micro-optimization.